# Do I need to close response?

Tags: retrofit2

If the response is mapped to an object, like that:

```
@GET("accountId")
@WorkerThread
Call<ResponseBody> getUserData(@Header(NetworkConstants.Header.AUTHORIZATION) String accessToken);
```

Is it necessary to do response.body().close() ?

Comment: I am getting cannot make a new request because the previous response is still open: please call response.close()

Comment: DId you have any solution?

Comment: the answer was - no need to close, except if using @Streaming annotation. That's not the case in this example.

Comment: @POST(ApiConstant.LOGIN)
    Call<ResponseBody> userLogin(@Body JsonObject jobj); ==> My code in interface. I have a clarification. Is it good to use ResponseBody here or Shall I use the retrofit Response and create modal class for each response

Comment: I am not using streaming annotation. But still facing the above issue

Comment: According to the documentation you are facing different issue.

Comment: Can you give the documentation or did you have any solution?

Comment: hmm. here they write that it has to be closed: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/#the-response-body-must-be-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and only if you are using @Streaming annotation on the method then it is necessary to do response.body().close().
Otherwise it is fully buffered.